# Problemas com função jQuery de impressão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera montei um código em jQuery para realizar algumas alterações no meu layout ocultando algumas div e imprimindo a página. Ela funciona muito bem, porém estou tendo o seguinte problema.

Quando tenho imagem na minha página, o sistema imprime antes de carregar as imagens. Como faço para que so seja impresso após o carregamento total da página.

Segue meu código:

```
    <script>

    // Imprime a página
    window.print();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var beforePrint = function () {

            // Remove o loading
            $(".se-pre-con").hide();

            // Remove Menu topo
            $(".header").hide();
            $('body').css({"padding-top": "0px"});
        };
        var afterPrint = function () {
            // Redireciona página
            window.location = 'www.google.com.br';
        };

        if (window.matchMedia) {
            var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
            mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
                if (mql.matches) {
                    beforePrint();
                } else {
                    afterPrint();
                }
            });
        }

        window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
        window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
    }());
</script>
```

_______________________________ Estou tentando assim ______________________

```
    <script>

    var root = this;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var beforePrint = function () {

            // Remove o loading
            $(".se-pre-con").hide();

            // Remove Menu topo
            $(".header").hide();
            $('body').css({"padding-top": "0px"});
        };
        var afterPrint = function () {
            // Redireciona página
            window.location = 'google.com';
        };

        if (window.matchMedia) {
            var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
            mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
                if (mql.matches) {
                    beforePrint();
                } else {
                    afterPrint();
                }
            });
        }

        window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
        window.onafterprint = afterPrint;

        /* Imprime a página */
        root['print']();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só parar de chamar a função que você declarou no primeiro parâmetro de `$.fn.ready`. E agora você poderia chamar `this.print` no bloco dessa função.

No jQuery, esse evento "ready" acontece quando cada elemento de uma lista do jQuery tem sua propriedade `readyState` atribuida com `"complete"` (eu creio) – esse evento ao lado do `document` seria como esperar todo o conteúdo da página ser carregado e interpretado pelo navegador.

Lembrando, também existe o método `$.fn.on(event, callback)` para definir eventos no jQuery, se você preferir.

Também é possível você chamar o próprio jQuery para definir esse evento somente com o `document`: `$(callback)`, [mais informações](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

**Edit**: Até o evento "ready" do jQuery ser executado, suas imagens serão carregadas, mas não será possível saber se vão estar renderizadas na mesma hora. Para executar `print` você pode fazer um atraso com ajuda de `requestAnimationFrame` ou `setTimeout`. `requestAnimationFrame` seria ideal já que executa enquanto a página está ativa.

Eu acabei de criar uma [interface](https://github.com/nicematt/delayer-js) que usa **`requestAnimationFrame`** ou `setTimeout` para criar um atrasador com evento de contagem. Você pode forçar ele à não usar **`requestAnimationFrame`**. Quando **`requestAnimationFrame`** não é suportado a interface usa **`setTimeout`** para executar um atrasador.

Então aqui vai um exemplo com o uso dessa interface:

```
/*! Delayer.js */
;(function(a){"use strict";function c(a,c){var d=a[c];if(!d&&(c=c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substring(1)))for(var e=0,f=b.length;e<f&&!(d=a[b[e]+c]);++e);return d}function j(a,b){for(var c=0,d=a.events[b].length;c<d;++c){var e=a.events[b][c];e.call(e.target)}}function k(a){a.tId=d(function(){k(a)}),(a._elapsed=(a._now=f())-a._then)>a.wait&&(a._then=a._now-a._elapsed%a.wait,j(a,"count"))}function l(a){a.tId=setTimeout(function(){a.isRunning&&(j(a,"count"),l(a))},a.wait)}function m(a){for(var b,c=0,d=h.length;c<d;++c)if(h[c].identifier===a){b=h[i=c];break}return b}function n(){var b,a=h.length-1;if(a<0)b=0;else if(0===a){for(var c=0,d=h[0].identifier;c===d;++c);b=c}else for(var c=0;c<=a;++c)if(c>=a)b=c+1;else if((b=h[c].identifier+1)<h[c+1].identifier)break;this.identifier=b,g(this),h.push({delay:18,events:{count:[]},forceRAF:!0,identifier:b})}var i,b=["webkit","moz","ms"],d=c(a,"requestAnimationFrame"),e=c(a,"cancelAnimationFrame")||c(a,"cancelRequestAnimationFrame"),f="object"==typeof a.performance&&performance.now?function(){return performance.now()}:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},g="function"==typeof Object.defineProperty?function(a){var b=a.identifier;Object.defineProperty(a,"identifier",{value:b,writable:!1})}:Function.prototype,h=[];n.prototype={animation:function(a){var b=m(this.identifier);return"boolean"==typeof a&&(b.forceRAF=a,b.isRunning&&(b.stop(),b.start())),this},count:function(a){return"function"==typeof a&&this.on("count",a),this},delay:function(a){var b=m(this.identifier);return"number"==typeof a?(b.wait=a,b.isRunning&&(b.stop(),b.start()),this):b.wait},dismantle:function(){return this.stop(),h.splice(i,1),h.sort(function(a,b){return a.identifier-b.identifier}),!0},on:function(a,b){if(b.target=this,"function"==typeof b){for(var c=m(this.identifier),d=a.split(" "),e=0,f=d.length;e<f;++e){var g;typeof(!(g=c.events[d[e]])instanceof Array)&&(g=c.events[d[e]]=[]),g.push(b)}return this}},start:function(){var a=m(this.identifier);return a.isRunning=!0,(a.isUsingRAF=a.forceRAF&&"function"==typeof d)?(a._then=f(),k(a)):l(a),this},stop:function(){var a=m(this.identifier);return a.isRunning&&((a.isUsingRAF?e:clearTimeout)(a.tId),a.isRunning=!1),this}};var o=function(){return new n};"object"==typeof a.module&&module.exports?module.exports=exports=o:a.Delayer=o})(this);

var root = this

$(document).ready(function () {

    Delayer()

        .count(function() {
            /* Desmonta o atrasador. */
            this.dismantle()
            /* Imprime a página. */
            root.print()
        }

        .delay(500) // Esperaremos 500ms.
})
```

Em jQuery fazem algo um pouco similiar à isso para executar o evento `$.fn.ready` de cada elemento em uma lista (baseando em alguns posts do SOen),

```
;(function() {

    var isDocLoaded

    (isDocLoaded = function() {
        document['readyState'] === "complete" && callback()
    })()

    document['onreadystatechange'] = isDocLoaded

})();
```

Na verdade nem todo elemento tem a propriedade `readyState`. Alguns tem, como o `HTMLAudioElement`, `HTMLVideoElement`, etc, mas `Image`/`HTMLImageElement` tem eventos como "load" que podem acabar não acontecendo se o evento for definido depois de o recurso requisicionado carregar.

Comment: Bom tentei fazer da forma que vc explicou aqui, e não esta funcionando, poderia me dar um exemplo com o meu código? quebrei a cabeça aqui e não da certo, ele imprime mas continua sem carregar as imagens

Comment: Não estou carregando ele no html mesmo. Vou editar minha pergunta para vc poder ver estou tentando ok

Comment: Olha troquei o `root['print']();` por `setTimeout(root.print, 1);` o unico problema e que ele leva 1 segunda para mandar o comando de imprimir.

Comment: bom o `requestAnimationFrame(root.print)` não funcionou, simplesmente não imprime. bom acho que o `setTimeout(root.print, 300)` não fica funcional para quem tem internet lenta, imagina se passa de 300ms e a imagem ainda não carregou. Vai dar problema certo.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. E, não, isso não depende da internet, as imagens já vão ter carregado antes de o callback do evento "ready" executar.

Answer (score 0):

Vou sugerir uma outra aproximação pra esse problema, que envolve o uso do evento [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). Apesar de o evento `ready` garantir que toda a estrutura do DOM já esteja construída, ele não garante que todos os *assets* (imagens, CSS e por aí vai) já foram totalmente carregados. Você pode fazer

```
$(document).on('load', function()){
    window.print();
}
```

para garantir que a instrução de impressão seja apenas disparada quanto as imagens já estiverem carregadas. [Esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready) do SO gringo fala sobre a diferença dos 2 eventos.

Quanto à esconder algumas coisas na versão de impressão (que eu acredito que é o que o resto do seu método faz), basta criar uma [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) (no seu arquivo .css, se é que ele existe) para [impressão](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/), da seguinte maneira:

```
@media print{
    .se-pre-con, header{
        display: none;
    }
    body{
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```